# How to apply multiple group-by conditions to perform an operation on a column in pandas data frame?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I am a beginner in python. 
I have data frame in this form:

```
  A B C
0 1 2 0.65
1 2 3 0.01
2 3 1 0.34
3 3 1 0.11
4 2 3 0.02
5 2 3 0.12
```

I want values in C column to be added whenever I get the same values in columns A and B in 2 or more consecutive rows. I have several values that I want to match.
Output should be something like this:

```
  A B C
0 1 2 0.65
1 2 3 0.01
2 3 1 0.45
3 2 3 0.14
```

I did search for a solution and got this code:

```
res = df.groupby(by=[df.A.ne(2).cumsum(), 'A', df.B.ne(3).cumsum(), 'B'], as_index=False).agg({'C': 'sum'})
```

this code gives me the sum of the last two rows only. I want to be able to do it at once.

Thanks, 
Sarah

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you are really close , just adding a `diff`

```
s1,s2 = df.A.diff().ne(0).cumsum(),df.B.diff().ne(0).cumsum()
df.groupby([s1,s2]).agg({'A':'first','B':'first','C':'sum'})
Out[95]: 
     A  B     C
A B            
1 1  1  2  0.65
2 2  2  3  0.01
3 3  3  1  0.45
4 4  2  3  0.14
```

Comment: Great thanks, how can I append column C to my original df? with the correct row index?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to achieve what you want using boolean masking

```
   indices = []
   for index, row in df.iterrows():
       if row.A == row.B:
           if df.loc[index-1, 'A'] == df.loc[index-1, 'B']:
               indices.append(index)

   df[df.index.isin(indices)].C.sum()
```